# generalize purescript function using MonadAff

Tags: purescript

I have a question about generalizing. Starting with this function:

```
test0 :: String -> String
test0 s = s
```

we can generalize it in its argument:

```
test1 :: forall a. Show a => a -> String
test1 s = show s
```

or in its functional result:

```
test12 :: forall a. Show a => String -> a
test12 s = s
```

Now consider the following function:

```
test2 :: forall e. Aff e Int
test2 s = pure 0
```

I would like to generalize it in its functional result:

```
test3 :: forall e m. MonadAff e m => m e Int
test3 s = pure 0
```

However, I now get an error:
Could not match kind type with kind # Control.Monad.Eff.Effect while checking the kind of MonadAff e m => m e Int in value declaration test3.

I cannot understand why. Moreover, I've found an example of similar such generalizing in Hyper.Node.Server, for example in this type:

```
write :: forall m e. MonadAff e m => Buffer -> NodeResponse m e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `MonadAff e m` asserts that the monad `m` somehow wraps `Aff e` somewhere inside. But it doesn't assert that monad `m` itself must have a type argument `e`. That would be awfully restrictive, wouldn't it?

Therefore, when constructing your return type, don't apply `m` to `e`:

```
test3 :: forall e m. MonadAff e m => m Int
test3 = pure 0
```

The example you found is quite different. Here, the function is not returning a value in `m`, like in your `test3`, but rather a value `NodeResponse`, which is a [wrapper around a function that returns `m Unit`](https://github.com/owickstrom/hyper/blob/v0.8.0/src/Hyper/Node/Server.purs#L60-L61).

Comment: I see. Thank you! However, the resulting expression is still not OK, I find. The type does not describe the functional argument. Only if I change it to 
test3 :: forall e m. MonadAff e m => Int -> m Int
the compiler accepts it.

Comment: `test3` doesn't need to accept an argument if you want to type it as `m Int` - it should just be `test3 = pure 0`

Comment: Quite true, @gb. However, I just wanted to point out that my original expression(s) contained two errors, not just one.